# Using a date as a variable in a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How do you use date as a variable in a where clause?  I can't seem to understand how it works.

```
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.mopid, 
       TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.mopstart, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') SOM, 
       TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.mopend, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') EOM
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY  
WHERE MOPACTIVITY.mopstart BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-JAN-14'
```

What is the correct syntax for the code above? I am trying to run this from the Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Note that your where clause will not return rows where mopstart is after midnight on 30-JAN-14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would work with quotes around the constants:

```
$a = '2014-01-01 00:00:00';
$b = '2014-01-31 23:59:59';

SELECT MOPACTIVITY.mopid, 
       TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.mopstart, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') SOM, 
       TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.mopend, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') EOM
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY  
WHERE TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.mopstart, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') BETWEEN $a AND $b;
```

In practice, though, it is usually better to convert the constants to the type of the column rather than vice versa:

```
WHERE MOPACTIVITY.mopstart BETWEEN to_date($a, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')  AND
                                   to_date($b, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```

By not changing the type of the column, Oracle can more easily take advantage of an index on that column.

Comment: I get the following error on the first code you replied with:     ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first

Comment: @JonathanMorningstar . . . I was following the template you used in the question.  If this is PL/SQL, then you need to declare the variables and assign them.  Your code looks a bit more like php-style variables.

Comment: I am using Oracle.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JonathanMorningstar . . . Perhaps you are looking for "bind variables".  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/sqlplus.816/a75664/ch34.htm.